# $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE Then set_flashdata() is not working properly in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

When i set

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

Then after if i am using

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message','record updated');
```

It will be destroyed all session data.

If i am doing false

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

Then `set_flashdata()` is working and does not destroyed session data.

Please give me advice how we can resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is not due to flashdata (might be useragent issue). can you please paste other $config for session.

Comment: $config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'cisession';
$config['sess_match_ip']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

Comment: ok try using
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;

Comment: $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE; then after it will be start session destroyed

Comment: yes but if $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE; and $config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE; your session is still destroyed. If no then its issue with useragent. Please let me know if so

Comment: Yes i had tried above. But it destroyed session

Comment: ok. so do one thing before setting flash message print user_data and user_agent of CI_session. and while setting flash message change for same in session class. Its just beacuse data is truncate due to some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84807/discussion-between-krutssss-and-user1048123).

Answer (score 1):

You can select between the "Files driver" (default) and the "Database driver".

When you want to use the Database driver edit two lines in the config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';  // select database driver
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';  // name of the mysql table
```

Session table (Codeigniter 3.x):

Edit in config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';  // select database driver
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';  // name of the mysql table
```

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Session table (Codeigniter 2.x):

Edit in config.php

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';  // name of the mysql table
```

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Comment: This function is codeigniter 3.0. Now its not stable. I am using 2.1.4

Comment: @krutssss I edited my answer for CI 2.x. The table is a bit different. And the config file to.

Comment: I had already do this type. Now its display this error Message: Undefined index: subclass_prefix

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 238

Comment: Do you have this line in your config.php file?

$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

Comment: No. I haven't this line

Comment: So this line is per default in the config file. So you should add it. That's why you get this error!